# Volley json parsing displays nothing in ListView

Tags: android

I would like to display movie titles from themoviedb.org. But the applications is not displaying anything in the ListView. Here is my code:

```
try{
JsonObjectRequest request = new JSonObjectRequest(Request.Method.Get,url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
try{
JSONArray titlesArray =response.getJSONArray("results");
for(int i=0;i<titlesArray.length();i++){`
JSONObject inner = titlesArray.getJSONObject(i);
String id=inner.getString("id");
String title =inner.getString("title");
String c= id+title;
arrayListMovies=new ArrayListMovies<>();
arrayListMovies.add(c);
}
RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

requestQueue.add(request);

And I am setting the arrayadapter to movieList ListView outside of the Volley function

```
moviesList = findViewById(R.id.listViewForMovies);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.android_simple_list_item1,arrayListMovies);
moviesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend make REST API calls the way you are doing, this is prone to errors, I recommend you to check about retrofit:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/

You have various problems with your code:

1. You are creating the adapter and assigning data before the call to the API completes.
2. You are creating the string list on every iteration of your titlesArray
3. You are not notifying the adapter that the list have changed.
4. Dont use a try block inside your response, because if there is errors with your code, it will be useful that the app crashes in order to get notified about this errors.

   ```
   public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
   private ArrayList<String> arrayListMovies = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
       this.myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.android_simple_list_item1, arrayListMovies);
       this.makeRequest();
   }

   public void makeRequest() {
       try {
           JsonObjectRequest request = new JSonObjectRequest(Request.Method.Get, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   JSONArray titlesArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                   arrayListMovies = new ArrayList<>();
                   for (int i = 0; i < titlesArray.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject inner = titlesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String id = inner.getString("id");
                       String title = inner.getString("title");
                       String c = id + title;
                       arrayListMovies.add(c);
                   }
                   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Note some things: I have moved the adapter and arrayListMovies declarations to the top of the class.
I initialize the adapter before making the api call.
In the response of the network call I create the arrayListMovies ONCE.
At the end i call myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to refresh the adapter data.